# Is there a way to rebind an event handler referenced in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/) plug-in on a site I'm building.  I'm currently working on an administrator page and want to disable the overlay click event handler until the user has successfully authenticated. I can successfully unbind all event handlers using `$("#lean_overlay").off("click");`, but I'm unable unbind/rebind the specific event handler when it's stored in a variable.  I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and the most up-to-date leanModal.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
var overlay_event = $._data($('#lean_overlay')[0], "events");
$('#lean_overlay').off('click', overlay_event);
    // insert code to check if user's logged in
$('#lean_overlay').on('click', overlay_event);
```

Is this the proper way to store a handler in a variable using jQuery 1.8+?

**EDIT:**

I neglected to mention that I've tried `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` to stop the event from firing.  My logic for checking the user's authentication state is working.  What's not working is the disabling of the click event handler for the overlay to force users to use the login modal before accessing the page. I'm unsure if that was clear in my original post.  Storing the event handler seemed like the best option...

**2nd EDIT:**

I figured out how to stop the overlay click event handler from firing using a botched version of namespacing:

`$('#lean_overlay').off('click', $(this).leanModal.close_modal);`

The removal of the event handler works, but the re-bind doesn't appear to be working.  I can't seem to find an easy way of re-binding an event handler function found in a linked plug-in.  Ideas?

Comment: Rather than binding and unbinding events, which can be expensive, try setting a flag on the user authentication and checking for that flag at the beginning of your handler.

Comment: @TNguyen Just edited my post...if I used a flag instead, how would I still prevent the overlay click event handler from executing?

Comment: Try event.stopPropagation() to stop the event.

Comment: @TNguyen Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.  Both didn't seem to work.  One thing I did discover is that the overlay is clicked upon page load, something I wasn't aware of.  I've edited my logic to account for the extra overlay "clicks," and while the logic is working, preventing the overlay click event handler still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no way I could find to "capture" the event handler referenced by the plug-in.  My solution was to make my own overlay and use that for the login screen.  Works perfectly because it's MINE! :)